# yii2 Why I can't store the data in database?

Tags: php, yii2

Why I can't store the data in database?

```
 $TposDuang = new TposDuang();
                $TposDuang->tposid=5;
                $TposDuang->duangresid=162;
                $TposDuang->tposresid=1;
                $TposDuang->save();
```

The database is unable to store this information.

Comment: What did you do before you posted the question here? 
Did you check the return value of the `save()` call?

Comment: Thank you very much,Problem solving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check this :

```
if ($TposDuang->validate()) {
    $TposDuang->save();
    // all inputs are valid
} else {
   // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
   $errors = $$TposDuang->errors;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, according to your solution, the problem is solved.